# Need a light-weight remote desktop utility that doesn't eject the user (other than teamviewer)

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-assistance

I need a desktop assistance application similar to windows' but that allows both users to interact with the PC.

I prefer it to be light-weight and free.
Also I don't like Team Viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in Windows Remote Desktop and apply the concurrent users patch to enable two people to log in and use the PC at the same time.

I've used it to update software on the HTPC without preventing someone from watching TV at the same time.

http://lifehacker.com/5873717/enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-with-this-patch

Comment: Thanks Richard. I actually found that out yesterday but still ty :)